# Differentiate between website endpoint from REST API endpoint for AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, boto, botocore

I have an input provided by a user, that would be used as the endpoint url for bucket operations for an S3 bucket.
Is there a way to differentiate if the url is a REST API endpoint or a website endpoint?

I did read: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteEndpoints.html
which mentions "Supports only GET and HEAD requests on objects" for a website endpoint.
However, i have come across cases where the other operations worked even with a website endpoint.

I am using python boto3 for these APIs.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question... but isn't the main difference that the website endpoint contains `s3-website` in its URI?

Comment: You are right, i implemented it by checking for the substring of "s3-website". This does not cover all the cases, but good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

With only S3 you can't upload any data. It's a static website hosting, without any logic or ability to process data. You're just storing files that browser renders.

If you need logic I'd suggest adding some Lambda functions with REST endpoint. For your needs, you'll probably stay in free tier.